# Link with id doesn't work if page height changes dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

The structure that I'm dealing with is like this:

```
<html>
    <header>
         <a href="#footer">scroll to footer</a>
    </header>
    <section id="gallery"></section>
    <footer id="footer"></footer>
</html>
```

Obviously, I'm expecting to scroll to `#footer` when link is clicked, but the problem is that `#gallery` is loaded after page loads, and the height of whole page changes. Link scrolls only to that place where `#footer` was before `#gallery` was loaded.

The example of gallery I'm using: http://tympanus.net/Development/GammaGallery/

The jQuery code that I'm using to make smooth scrolling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')  
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')  
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 600);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `.offset()` when the event handler function is called simply by placing your `targetOffset` assignment within the function:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 600);
    return false;
});
```